# Update Lemonstand partial onClosed FancyBox

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm using Lemonstand for a web shop, and I want to update a partial when I close a FancyBox. 
To trigger an update for a partial on the same page, i.e. a button, I do this:

```
onClick="return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('foo', {update: {'foo_page': 'foo_partial'}})"
```

But now I want to do this when closing the FancyBox. I know how to reload the entire parent page using the onClosed option in FancyBox. But I don't want reload the entire page, only the partial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `onclick` function inside a fancybox callback

...for fancybox v1.3.4

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 "onClosed": function(){
   return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('foo', {update: {'foo_page': 'foo_partial'}});
 }
});
```

...for v2.x

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 afterClose: function(){
   return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('foo', {update: {'foo_page': 'foo_partial'}});
 }
});
```

**NOTE** : In your `onclick` inline declaration

```
onClick="return $(this) ....."
```

... it is not clear to me what `$(this)` is making reference to ... so you may need to define such selector inside the fancybox callback.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't far off. The solution was to give the form on the parent page an ID, and then make the call to said ID.

```
'onClosed'      : function() {
    return $('#form_id').getForm().sendRequest('foo', {update: {'foo_page': 'foo_partial'}})
}
```

Comment: that was the comment in my answer "__...`$(this)` ... so you may need to define such selector inside the fancybox callback.__"